# Getting the offset height of a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing the height of div in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500253/accessing-the-height-of-div-in-javascript)

We're trying to alter [msdropdown](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) to "drop up" if the menu will go off the frame. In order to figure if that's going to happen we need to check the location of the drop down box relative to the frame that it's in. From there it's easy make the thing open upwards, but the location is troubling us. Getting the element by id doesn't seem to reach through the several frames to the one we're using. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery offset might help you in getting relative position of dropdown.

Read [more about it](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)