# Accessing the height of div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div :

**css**

```
    div { width: 200px; height:auto }
```

**markup**

```
   <div contenteditable="true"> Text is editable </div>
```

Now what should i do to access the `height ( numeric value )` of the above div in javascript ? I tried

`$('div').height()` & `$('div').css("height");` both returns `auto`.

Comment: Both work fine http://jsfiddle.net/sySFk/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to try [`.innerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/) or [`.outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/), depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$('div').innerHeight()
```

or

```
$('div').outerHeight()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
if(divs.length>0)
     divs[0].offsetHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

For returning the **NUMERIC height value** :

```
document.getElementsById('myElementId').offsetHeight; // Without jQuery

$('#myElementId').outerHeight(); // With jQuery
```

*Note 1: outerHeight(true) returns the size with margin and padding inclued, more informations on http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/*

*Note 2 : innerHeight() returns the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding but not border.*

*Note 3: $('div').height() or $('div').css("height") returns the css value only.*